# Rails 3.1 with jquery & backbone,js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Is there any turotial to use both backbone js and Jquery together with rails 3.1

Comment: These <a href="http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=backbone">railscasts</a> were very helpful in learning the basics of integrating rails and backbone. Here's a tutorial from 42 floors about <a href="http://42floors.com/blog/posts/user-authentication-with-rails-and-backbone-js">user authentication</a>. Those might be helpful for you or others searching for similar material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yea, there are many tutorials.

[BackboneScreencasts.com](http://backbonescreencasts.com/) has some good screencasts.

[Backbonefu.com](http://backbonefu.com/) has many good articles on using backbone.

Thoughtbot is making an [ebook](https://workshops.thoughtbot.com/backbone-js-on-rails) on integrating Backbone and rails.

And there are many other resources on the web.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great gem to easy even more Backbone's integration: https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

Answer (score 0):

Here's an overview on using Backbone.js in Rails 3.1: http://codetunes.com/2012/01/03/backbone-js-rails-3-asynchronous-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone mention this tutorial yet, which I used to get started:

[CloudEdit: A Backbone.js tutorial with Rails](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/)

[... and part 2](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/09/backbone.js-tutorial-with-rails-part-2/)